# OO Javascript - Should I let a class add itself to the DOM or let it return an element to then add to the DOM?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I am practicing with OO Javascript, making a sort of web-app for viewing Manga (comics)

Right now I have a few classes:

- SearchResult
- Manga (generated from data out of the search result)
- Chapter (contained within Manga)
- Page (contained within Chapter)
- Image (contained within Page)

I add the search result to the DOM by generating the element's html and then appending this with jQuery.

This is where my question comes in:

Should I generate html (or a jQuery DOM element) and return this from a function in the class and then add this element outside the class or would it be wiser to give the class a reference to the container it should put elements in and let it put the elements into that container by appending?

So this?:

```
function(data, result, response) {
  var
    $resultContainer = $('<div/>', {class: 'row-fluid'}),
    maxResults = 10;

  for(var i in data) {
    if(i == maxResults) {
      break;
    }
    data[i].manga = Manga(data[i]);
    var res = new SearchResult(data[i]);
    res.setMyContainerElement($resultContainer);
    res.addResultToDOM();
  }
}
```

Or this?:

```
function(data, result, response) {
  var
    $resultContainer = $('<div/>', {class: 'row-fluid'}),
    maxResults = 10;

  for(var i in data) {
    if(i == maxResults) {
      break;
    }
    data[i].manga = Manga(data[i]);
    var res = new SearchResult(data[i]);
    $resultContainer.append(res.getHTML());
  }
}
```

In these examples the variable "data" is data from an AJAX call that returns a JSON-string containing the results, currently there is no limit to the amount of results returned, so I set it hard-coded, I will add this when I go into more detail on the server side, but for now this would be fine as I work on the front end.

If any additional information is required, please let me know, I will gladly update with any information I may have missed or is required, if it is available.

Comment: In theory the code is more reusable if you return the structure from the *worker function* and let the *manager function* that called it decide what to do with it. i.e. "Workers work and managers manage". Passing the container down the code tree adds dependencies :) It is not easy, but the best approach is to think that each function is being written for someone else and you want to be as helpful as possible.

Comment: That is what I thought as well and have done so far, but I thought about what would happen if you, for whatever crazy reason, had to change the way the class worked and it would have output something that would not be expected by whatever code was using the output of the class, this would mean a lot of refactoring. Edit: Though usually you should avoid this, since there is a lot of code that depends on the output of certain functions. Edit2: @TrueBlueAussie You are right, that way it works more like an API, of sorts, or a real life factory, outputting parts to be used by outside processes.

Comment: If you change the data structure, of course you will need to refactor, but that is preferable to moving decision-making/dependencies down to a lower level. If anything you want to be forced to review high-level code that is dependent on the data shape.

Comment: Good point. If anything, I should make whatever code that uses the output of these classes more flexible, while still maintaining the 'dependency' of expecting a jQuery DOM element or html string, you can't account for everything when creating these sorts of functions

Comment: Parameters to functions are only *badder* when they cause decisions to be made by the function (known as `command coupling`). Values for lookup and processing are *gooder* uses for parameters :)

Comment: While I'm not sure I understand the reasoning behind that post, I do agree you should not pass things like 'op' parameters into functions, changing the actions of said function, rather create multiple functions, each with their own actions, which, I believe, is called "Single-Responsibility"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54638/discussion-between-magikaas-and-trueblueaussie).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Moving comments to answer, as the question is mainly opinion-based and may well get closed :)

In theory the code is more reusable if you return the structure from the worker function and let the manager function that called it decide what to do with it. i.e. "Workers work and managers manage". Passing the container down the code tree adds dependencies :)

It is not easy, but the best approach is to think that each function is being written for someone else and you want to be as helpful as possible.

If you change the data structure, of course you will need to refactor, but that is preferable to moving decision-making/dependencies down to a lower level. If anything you want to be forced to review high-level code that is dependent on the data shape.

*With regard to parameters being dependencies:*

Parameters to functions are only *badder* when they cause decisions to be made by the function (known as command coupling). Values for lookup and processing are *gooder* uses for parameters :)

Answer (score 2):

In OOP, it would be backwards to return a View from a Model, so I'm going to recommend to NOT do that.

What you're really looking for here is a templating system -- a template means you have a piece of HTML sitting somewhere on your page, with value 'placeholders', and when you're ready to print your SearchResult, the template is cloned, placed in the page, and the 'placeholders' are filled with the actual values (e.g. the comic's title, cover image, etc.)

There are a lot of JavaScript templating systems. Off the top of my head:

- MustacheJS
- Handlebars
- DustJS
- KnockoutJS

I have experience with KnockoutJS so I can give you a preview of how it would look like in code (see the 'data-bind' tags, handled by KnockoutJS automatically):

```
<body>
   <!-- The contents of this DIV will be repeated for each 'manga' in 'mangas' -->
   <div class="manga-list" data-bind="forEach: mangas">
       <!-- This paragraph will be updated with the manga's 'title' value -->
       <p class="manga-title" data-bind="text: title"></p>

       <!-- This paragraph will be updated with the manga's 'cover' value (as src) -->
       <img class="manga-cover" data-bind="attr: {src: cover}" />
   </div>
</body>
<script>
   var viewModel = {
       mangas: ko.observableArray();
   };
   ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

   // ...
   // some code where you get your SearchResult
   // ...
   for (var i = 0; i < searchResult.length; i++)
   {
       viewModel.mangas.push(searchResult[i]);
   }
   // When the FOR loop above runs, your HTML is automatically updated.
<script>
```

Not sure if I'm 100% correct on the syntax above (maybe I'm missing a character or something) but it's by far my favourite binding/templating library, and it's pretty straigthforward to use.

Comment: Uh, `new SearchResult(data[i])` looks very much like a view, where `data[i].manga = Manga(data[i])` is the model. The question is whether a View (might it use templates or not) should apply them on a given DOM element or should return a DOM element.

Comment: Woah, my bad. Oh well, maybe this will allow some other visitors to discover the power of templating librairies; sorry this turned out irrelevant.

Comment: In my code, I have not applied anything like an MVC structure, I am still quite new to these sorts of OO programming structures, so applying them to Javascript OO is quite beyond my capabilties at present, if you were implying I had an underlying MVC structure for handling these classes and their output. The classes are controllers, views and models all at the same time, would it be wiser to implement an MVC structure to this sort of code (given my experience) or would that either over-complicate and/or be too big of a jump at this point? I am still early in the process of this application.

Comment: Well it sounds to me like you already have model 'classes' (putting quotations because in JavaScript the concept is a bit loose), but I think using a templating system will not be too hard to learn (KnockoutJS has one of the best and most concise documentation!) and will really, really save you a lot of time and headaches in the long run. It's pretty much a given you will into a scenario where it's useful -- you've got data stored in JS objects, and you want to display them via HTML, it's bound to happen. Have a peek at my example code, essentially Knockout boils down to that.

Answer (score 0):

> Should I generate html or a jQuery DOM element

DOM element, definitely.

> Should I return this from a function in the class and then add this element outside the class or would it be wiser to give the class a reference to the container it should put elements in?

Both approaches are quite fine. Which one to choose should depend on whether your class instance does *occupy the complete container*.

If so, it's fine to pass the container element to the constructor, and let the class code do whatever it wants to do with it. Most widgets work like that, and the method is favourably used by jQuery plugins that are called on the elements anyways.

If however your class does create a single element, and cannot be sure what to do with it, returning it would be better. As you say,

> let it put the elements into that container by appending

does not make it very reusable. What if you now want to put them in the container by prepending? The class does not know about this, it should simply yield its element to you. Those `.setMyContainerElement()` and `.addResultToDOM()` methods are nothing but boilerplate code, wrapping the equivalent jQuery methods. Better return the jQuery collection and let the caller do `.appendTo($containerElement)` (or `.prependTo($containerElement)`?).

Comment: When I said by appending, it was an example, I could append, prepend, replace, whatever would be required, depending on what the function wants to do. But I do see what you mean, I might as well use append instead of addResultToDOM, but I had to give it a reasonably descriptive name if I were to add it as a function to the class, I have for now reverted to returning a jQuery DOM element, which I can then use to my heart's content in any code using said class.

Comment: Well, the point is: Does you class know what is required, or would it need to cover all possibilities that the caller might want?

Comment: At present, it would only need to return a single DOM element, representing the SearchResult, which could then be added to a container for these SearchResults. So I guess this implies it has to cover all possibilities? I have not thought too thoroughly about the implementation and am still quite early in the development, setting up the structure of my classes and their respective functions.

Comment: By returning the DOM element, the caller (who uses the SearchResult, i.e. the example function you posted in your question) implicitly has all possibilites, he can do whatever he wants with it - even the things you had not thought of. No code in your `SearchResult` class is required for that.

Answer (score 0):

I tend to see custom views just as if they were native DOM elements and this aligns very well with web components.

When instanciating a new DOM element, it's not the element itself that has the responsability to render in it's container; otherwise the element would need to know about the context in which it is being rendered and that would be a very bad form of coupling.

Like @Bergi said, it is **less harmful** to let the component render itself in it's container if it's designed to occupy the whole container's space. Still, this practice often leads to having an extra container element for the sole purpose of positionning the view.

In short, I would say that if your view code is not designed to enhance an existing element, you should avoid giving it the responsability to render itself in it's container. The flexibility that you gain by leaving the rendering task up to the calling code easily surpass the added complexity.

PS: `DOM vs HTML strings = DOM` unless there are significant performance implications and you are willing to sacrifice on flexibility.